# Images not visible on Django site using field from models

Tags: python, django, image, amazon-s3

Novice django user here -- I have a model with a field 'page_image' in which I store the link to an image on s3 using boto. (bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/image.jpg). In my html page I am using , this works in development, but not in production. Why is the link not showing up only in production?

```
            {% for page in current_page.object_list %}
                <div>
                    <h3>
                        <img src="{{ page.page_image }}"
                        <a href="{{ page.page_url }}" class="link-font"> {{ page.page_title }} </a>
                        <small>${{ page.page_price }}</small>
                    </h3>
                    <h4 class="item-desc">
                        {{ page.page_desc|wordwrap:50}}
                    </h4>
                    <a href="{{ page.page_url }}">
                        <hr>
                    </a>
                </div> 
                <br>
                <br>
            {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Have you ran `manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: i just did, i still do not see the image. What is preventing from displaying the link which is within the field?, when I place a link to the image such as bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/image23.jpg it shows on the page, but the same text if in the 'page_image' field does not work.

Comment: What code are you using to call the image?

Comment: Please add your django template code where you call the image to your question.

Comment: Code added above. Line 4 is where I call the image. (<img src="{{ page.page_image }}")

Comment: Also useful would be posting the output (html) from your view. You can do this in your browser. Go to the page, select `View Source` or right-click and `Inspect`/`Inspect Element`, and look for the relevant chunk of output html. This will help in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple potential problems.  One is that, as posted, your `img` tag is missing a closing `>`.  The second is that if you're using an `ImageField` or a `FileField` in django, you'll want to use the `url` property for that field.  (If it's just a text field, ignore the second suggestion.)

So change:

```
                    <img src="{{ page.page_image }}"
```

To:

```
                    <img src="{{ page.page_image.url }}">
```

Or (if `page_image` is just a text/char field):

```
                    <img src="{{ page.page_image }}">
```

Comment: I am just missing the ending tag here, but that does not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

This has been a nightmare, apparently the issue was that once I transferred the .html file with changes, I was supposed to reboot services on the server.